# Large Volume Database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design, orm

We are creating a database where we store large number of records. We estimate millions (billions after few years) of record in one table and we always INSERT and rarely UPDATE or DELETE any of the record. Its a kind of archive system where we insert historic record on daily basis. We will generate different sort of reports on this historic record on user request so we've some concerns and require technical input from you people:

- What is the best way to manage this kind of table and database?
- What impact we may see in future for very large table?
- Is there any limitation on number of records in one table or size of table?
- How we suppose to INSERT bulk record from different sources (mostly from Excel sheet)?
- What is the best way to index large data tables?
- Which is the best ORM (object relational Mapping) should we use in this project?

Comment: A lot of questions in one post - and not all related to "Large Volume Database" - you would do well to split some of these out and provide more information.

Comment: This was already closed on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3074/630) for being too broad

Comment: What you require is a database specialist preferably with at least ten years of experience in high volume systems.

Answer (score 4):

You last statement sums it up. There is no ORM that will deal nicely with this volume of data and reporting queries: employ SQL experts to do it for you. You heard it here first.

Otherwise

- On disk: filegroups, partitioning etc
- Compress less-used data
- Is all data required? (Data retention policies)
- No limit of row numbers or table size
- INSERT via staging tables or staging databases, clean/scrub/lookup keys, then flush to main table: **DO NOT** load main table directly
- As much RAM as you can buy. Then add more.
- Few, efficient indexes
- Do you have parent tables or flat data mart? Have FKs but don't use them (eg bene update/delete in parent table) so no indexes needed
- Use a SAN (easier to add disk space, more volumes etc)
- Normalise

Some of these are based on our experiences of around 10 billion rows through one of our systems in 30 months, with peaks of 40k rows+ per second.

See this too for high volume systems: [10 lessons from 35K tps](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/12/12/10-lessons-from-35k-tps.aspx)

Summary: do it properly or not at all...

Comment: Absolutely, if you plan on having a high volume system, hire an expert to design it.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the best way to manage this kind of table and database?**

If you are planning to store billions of records then you'll be needing plenty of diskspace, I'd recommend a 64bit OS running SQL 2008 R2 and as much RAM and HD space as is available. Depending on what performance you need I'd be tempted to look into SSDs.

**What impact we may see in future for very large table?**

If you have the right hardware, with a properly indexed table and properly normalized the only thing you should notice are the reports will begin to run slower. Inserts may slow down slightly as the Index file becomes bigger and you'll just have to keep an eye on it.

**Is there any limitation on number of records in one table or size of table?**

On the right setup I described above, no. It's only limited by disk space.

**How we suppose to INSERT bulk record from different sources (mostly from Excel sheet)?**

I've run into problems running huge SQL queries but I've never tried to import from very large flat files.

**What is the best way to index large data tables?**

Index as few fields as necessary and keep them to numerical fields only.

**Which is the best ORM (object relational Mapping) should we use in this project?**

Sorry can't advise here.

Answer (score 0):

Billions of rows in a "few years" is not an especially large volume. SQL Server should cope perfectly well with it - assuming your design and implementation is appropriate. There is no particular limit on the size of a table. Stick to solid design principles: normalize your tables, choose keys and data types carefully and have a suitable partitioning and indexing strategy.